# Receiving image as stream through Java Spring Boot via REST POST

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm creating a project in Java with Spring Boot. 
The focus is to receive an image that is converted to a stream and that my code converts this image to a pdf file and sends this pdf back as a stream.
Despite the analysis, I can't get past the beginning, receiving the stream.. .

Here you'll see a snippet of my postman call to the running project
[image]

My **Controller** looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @PostMapping(value = "/convert/{format}", consumes = "application/octet-stream", produces = "application/octet-stream")
    @ResponseBody
    public void convert(RequestEntity<InputStream> entity, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String format, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
        if ("pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(format)) { 
            PDFConverter cnv = new PDFConverter();
            /*cnv.convert(entity.getBody(), response.getOutputStream(), params);*/
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.getOutputStream().println("hello binary");
        } else {
            // handle other formats
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal format: " + format);
        }
    }
}
```

What do I overlook in this case?

Comment: Just to eliminate POSTMAN clouding up things, can you try your request with curl ?

Comment: Good point! I tried this already with following command: curl -F "file=@streamFile.stream;type=application/octet-stream" localhost:8080/convert/pdf but this gave me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, in the controller I used `RequestEntity<InputStream> entity`, this gave the error. After changing this to `HttpServletRequest request` it worked.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value="/convert/{format}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void convert(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String format, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        try{
            if ("pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(format)) {
                PDFConverter cnv = new PDFConverter();
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                cnv.convert(request.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream(), params);
            } else {
                // handle other formats
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal format: " + format);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message tells you already, your content-type is not valid. You expecting a different content Type than you are sending off. Might be the problem that you append the charset definition to the request.

Comment: I don't append the charset by purpose, is this a by default setting? When I deselect the content-type set in the header it gives me the following error message: "message": "Invalid mime type \"false\": does not contain '/'",

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using commons-fileupload's streaming API. This won't work if `spring.http.multipart.enabled=true`, due to the request being pre-processed. Can you try setting `spring.http.multipart.enabled=false` and also change `consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }`,

Comment: I actually use webMethods Integration Server to call the POST method inside my Java project, this will send through the stream . The problem situates if I want to imitate this stream in postman/curl because the localhost runs not on the same server as webMethods. It will not recognize the content-type of the stream I put in the binary field

Comment: I found the solution, in the controller I used RequestEntity<InputStream> entity, this gave the error. After changing this to HttpServletRequest request it worked